# blank space between divs even though margin and padding are set to 0

Tags: html, css

i am trying to build a css framework for my personal use.
i have experienced this problem before on other projects but managed to fix it by altering the code. i have no idea why this happens

```css
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.row{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.col-sm-1,.col-md-1,.col-lg-1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:4.16667%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see in the code snippet there is blank space when you run therefore resulting in less divs in the row. i tried inspecting it with chrome but the blank space shows as part of the body. i have literally no margins and no paddings at all

Comment: this doesn't happen on inline block only

Comment: The solution is the same, regardless of whether it’s `inline-block` or something else.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the white space between inline-blocks.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block">A</div> <!-- There is a white-space here --><div style="display:inline-block">B</div>
```

You can avoid this by packing the divs together seamlessly (although ugly):

```html
<div style="display:inline-block"></div
><div style="display:inline-block></div>
```

This eliminates the spaces between the tags which actually do get parsed!

Another way to avoid this is instead of

```css
display:inline-block
```

using

```css
float:left
```

which, however, requires a

```css
clear:both
```

on the container, to prevent layout issues.

Comment: float:left fixes it, but why would i want clear: both? that just puts them on new lines. i do not want that, anyway thank you :)

Comment: after all floating content you should set an element with clear:both, otherwise the following content may be placed somewhere...

Comment: Always put `clear: both` on the container of floated elements, otherwise you'll have serious layout issues.

Answer (score 2):

Changed to display:block and float:left; and works fine.

```css
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.row{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.col-sm-1,.col-md-1,.col-lg-1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:4.16667%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
    </div>
```